# Determining the probability of being offered a certain number of resources

Tags: probability

There are $32$ kingdoms. They each have a $4\%$ chance that they will offer me resources every year. Of the $32$ kingdoms, what is the probability that at least one kingdom will offer me resources.

How would I then go about figuring out subsequent amounts of kingdoms offering resources, (at least 2/32 kingdoms; at least 3/32 kingdoms; and so forth)?

I thought that it would be something like this:

If the chance of ALL kingdoms offering resources is 1/800, 1/(25x32), then the math would be something like 32/25 - 1/800 = 1023/800 = 1.27 = 127% of at least ONE kingdom happening? If this math is completely wrong, please edit this portion out, but if I am somewhere near the right answer, please help my figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Help with a better title would be appreciated as well.

Comment: That's because it's the same question. I didn't understand your last very vague answer, and my question was placed on hold, leading to no further answers.

Comment: Theres no reason to vote this question down, its perfectly legitimate!

Comment: Well, I can't decide on which of the answers has offered me the most help, as they are all great answers. For that, I will leave it to the community, so I thank you all for your teachings! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

$$P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

where in our case

$$n=32$$

$$p=0.04$$

We have
$$\begin{align*}
P(X\geq1)
&=1-P(X=0)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Similarly

$$\begin{align*}
P(X\geq2)
&=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

and so forth.

Can you go from here?

Comment: I understand P is for "probability" and n is for "number of kingdoms", I think. What is the X and k? I'm sorry for sounding so ignorant, but I really appreciate the lesson.

Comment: $n$ is the number of trials. $X$ is the random variable which denotes how many "successes" you get in those $32$ trials, which has expectation $np=32\cdot0.04$. $k$ is the value that the random variable $X$ takes on.

Comment: So, P(X≥3) = 1- P(x=0)- P(X =1) - P(X =2)? Which basically means the probability that at least 3 or more kingdoms will grant resources?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I'll adopt a weird notation for this: pretend that the probability that you get resources from a particular kingdom is just R, if they offer you nothing, I'll use N.

## One Kingdom

So if there was one kingdom, the possible outcomes are, you either get resources (a 4% chance) or you don't (96% chance); but we know that probabilities have to sum to one, so:

$$ R + N = 0.04 + 0.96 = 1$$

So this is all well and good

## Two Kingdoms

Now if there are two kingdoms, you could use a tree diagram like:

```
-----|--K1_resources----|-----K2_resources
     |                  |-----K2_nothing
     |
     |---K1_nothing-----|-----K2_resources
                        |-----K2_nothing
```

So there are four possible outcomes, and you can calculate the associated probabilities just fine, eg: k1_resources * k2_resources = 0.04 * 0.04 which it seems that you are pretty comfortable with:

### A simper Alternative

Its actually much simpler to just enumerate the terms like this:

$$ (R + N) ( R + N) = (R+N)^2 = R^2 + 2 RN + N^2 $$

Now the probability that you get aide twice is just $R^2 = 0.0016$, that you get aide once $2RN=2 * 0.04 * 0.96= 0.0768$ and that you get no aide $N^2 = 0.96*0.96 = 0.9216$.

This is much simpler as you don't need to worry about which kingdom is actually giving you the aide.

## Lots of Kingdoms

Now you can probably figure that if I have lots of kingdoms, we can say 32 as you did in your example, thats equivalent to expanding:

$$ (R + N)^{32} $$

This can easily be done by using pascals triangle, the answer will just be:

$$ (R+N)^{32} = \sum_{k=0}^{32} \binom {32}{k} R^k N^{32-k} $$

If you haven't seen this result before, I'd point you [to this explanation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/polynomial-functions/binomial-theorem/v/binomial-theorem) which I think is excellent!

But then if you wanted the probability that you got aide from three kingdoms for example, that would just be:

$$ \binom{32}{3} R^3 N^{29} = 0.09716893  $$

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Oh thanks Remy, I missed the 1 when copying it :P

Comment: Thank you for the lesson. The step by step you've laid out is very helpful. I'm sure I can go off this to get all my answers and learn it well enough to utilize in the future.

Comment: So would (32   4) R^4*N^29 be how you solve for 4 kingdoms? And (32   5) R^5*N^28 for 5 and so forth?

Comment: Yes exactly :) Thats how you do it!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're having trouble conceptualising what's going on. First and foremost, the probability of something happening can never be more than $1$. In the same vein of thought, it can never be less than $0$. So, to that end, your answer is incorrect.

Supposing that kingdoms hand out resources independently, you can use the binomial distribution (as @Remy shows) to answer your question. By 'independently' I mean that if kingdom 1 gives you resources, it doesn't change the probability of whether or not kingdom 17 will give you resources, or whether kingdom 21 will or kingdom 31 will...and so forth.

To break down your question lets consider the classic example. You're playing basketball, and you're not such a good shot - so you only make a basket with probability $0.2$.

Suppose then you make three consecutive and INDEPENDENT shots.

You can either make; $0$ shots, $1$ shot, $2$ shots or $3$ shots.

Now, ask yourself how many ways you can make $0$ shots in $3$ attempts. Well, there's $1$ way. Or, $3 \choose 0$.

Now, ask yourself how many ways you can make $1$ shot in $3$ attempts. Well, there's $3$ ways. Or, $3 \choose 1$.

Now, ask yourself how many ways you can make $2$ shots in $3$ attempts. Well, there's $3$ ways also. Or, $3 \choose 2$.

Now, ask yourself how many ways you can make $3$ shots in $3$ attempts. Well, there's $1$ way. Or, $3 \choose 3$.

To get the probability of making $1$ shot, just multiply the probability of you making a given shot by the number of ways you can make $1$ shot AND the probability that you miss $2$ shots.

So, ${3 \choose 1} \cdot 0.20 \cdot 0.80^2$

To get the probability of making $2$ shots, just multiply the probability of you making a given shot by the number of ways you can make $2$ shots AND the probability that you miss a shot.

So, ${3 \choose 2} \cdot 0.20^2\cdot 0.80$

Hopefully you can now see the classic form of the [binomial distribution](http://www.statisticshowto.com/binomial-distribution-formula/) forming,

$$Pr(X = k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Here, ${n \choose k}$ rears it's when you're trying to count the number of ways something can occur when you don't care about how they're ordered. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Here, $X$ is just what we call a random variable. It can be, in your 'kingdom scenario', any number from $0$ to $32$. $k$ is just the value that $X$ takes on. $p$ is the probability of success, which in your case, is being given resources. $1 - p$ is the probability of not being given any resources (read about the complement rule (i.e. $1-p$) [here](https://www.ck12.org/probability/complement-rule-for-probability/lesson/Complement-Rule-for-Probability-ADV-PST/)). Finally, $n$ is the total number of trials. In your case, it's just the number of kingdoms.

Comment: It seems you understand that I'm new to this whole binomial distribution. Thank you, this is a great answer. I think, with a little more research and learning a bit more about it all, I can now use your steps and breakdown to help me get my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for assuming that you had to prior knowledge. Probability can get messy quick, and like anything - it's important to get the basics down pat. I would strongly recommend watching some videos on Khan Academy about probability, then come back to the answers here when you're comfortable.

Comment: That was my exact plan, and no worries. Math may not be my strong suit, but I'm an intelligent individual, and as I think you know, it's hard for us more academically inclined to remember that not everyone is near our skill level. I've found the greatest test to us knowing something is whether or not we can explain our field of knowledge well enough to help a child understand it. Hint: Explain to me like I'm five. :) (My strong suits are psychology and philosophy.)

Comment: Okay, so I'm on my way to understanding all of this, but I do have one question. What is the point of X or k if they are the same thing? Or are they different things with the same value? Either way, I'm confused because they seem redundant. Why not just have either X or k?

Comment: @Arcemius It just comes down to notation really. You're right in a sense, We say $X$ is a discrete random variable, which means that it can take on non-negative whole number values. The $k$ part is what we call the 'realisation' of $X$. This is just a fancy word for the value of $X$ we so happened to observe. The reason we use random variables is because we can describe their outcomes, or 'realisations' with probability distributions. For example, we use notation like $X \sim Pois$ to say $X$'s possible outcomes follow the probability distribution know as a 'Poisson distribution'.

Comment: Really, it's just by convention we write $Pr(X = k)$. For example, think about when you capitalise a letter after a full stop. I still know what you mean, anyone else does too. It basically just falls down to a matter of convention.